# how to get newest and previous book code within a table with composite key

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have a table with two primary keys(student_id and borrow_numbers)
, i want to get newest book borown in a field and display previous book borown code for a  book for the same student ,
 if the student hasn't a previous borrow for a book keep the field null.

data in a table

[image: data in a table]: 
**pink color** :composite key 
**blue**:newest book code 
**red**:previous of the newest book code

the code :

```
select student,Newest_book_code,previous_book_code from(
select student_id student,book_code  Newest_book_code,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  book_code order by date_of_borrow desc ) ddt
book_code in(select book_code from books where row_number(over() partition  book_code order by date_of_borrow desc ) -1  )   previous_book_code 
from books
)where ddt=1
```

the output wanted :

[image: the output wanted]

Any Help ?

Comment: Please do not include data as images as it is not accessible to people using screen readers and we cannot copy/paste the values; the best solution is to include DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements as text that we can copy/paste and execute to recreate your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You want to partition the `ROW_NUMBER` by student and not by book. Then you want the values that correspond to the row numbers of `1` and `2` and can transpose that from multiple rows into multiple columns of a single row using a `PIVOT` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT student_id AS student,
         book_code,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY student_id
            ORDER BY date_of_borrow DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM  books
)
PIVOT (
  MAX( book_code )
  FOR rn IN (
    1 AS newest_book_code,
    2 AS previous_book_code
  )
)
```

or, using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT student,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN book_code END ) AS newest_book_code,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN book_code END ) AS previous_book_code
FROM   (
  SELECT student_id AS student,
         book_code,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY student_id
            ORDER BY date_of_borrow DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM  books
)
GROUP BY student
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE books ( student_id, borrow_numbers, book_code, date_of_borrow ) AS
SELECT 1001, 1, 123, SYSDATE - 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 2, 234, SYSDATE - 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 3, 345, SYSDATE - 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2002, 1, 111, SYSDATE - 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2002, 2, 222, SYSDATE - 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2002, 3, 333, SYSDATE - 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2002, 4, 444, SYSDATE - 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3003, 1, 456, SYSDATE - 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3003, 2, 567, SYSDATE - 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4004, 1, 999, SYSDATE - 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | STUDENT | NEWEST_BOOK_CODE | PREVIOUS_BOOK_CODE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1001 | 345 | 234 |
> | 2002 | 444 | 333 |
> | 3003 | 567 | 456 |
> | 4004 | 999 | *<null>* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d9acbc08e4ddcd43cffc638e13d7462)*

Comment: i got this error! 
pivot(MAX(book_code) FOR rn IN(1 AS newest_book_code,2 AS previous_book_code)
     *

ERROR at line 11:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @rko As you can see from the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6fac874d810f0a4c097ba291017625ee), the code works there. With only a snippet of code from your comment it is impossible to determine why you got that error; you are going to have to debug it or else provide a [MRE] that replicates the issue (perhaps copy your code to a db<>fiddle and see whether the error is still there and what the differences are to my code).

Comment: i checked the code in db<>fiddle  it works well but, my oracle 10g looks not applicable with pivot function that why it shows the error !

Comment: @rko Your question is tagged Oracle11g.... Oracle10g is very old, they're up to Oracle 21c now so perhaps you might consider upgrading to a newer version. You will probably have to use conditional aggregation instead.

Comment: sorry bro ,tagged mistakenly to oracle 11g im using 10g because isql* plus is working only in 10g version and it's amazing for coding instead sql developer and others